# How to add space before text in the input field [flutter]

Tags: flutter

I have this TextField in flutter which I'm going to use to take string input from the user. Right now it looks like as follows:

[image]

Now what I want is to give some space before `What` so that it doesn't look so left aligned. How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `contentPadding` property of the `InputDecoration` widget in Flutter to add padding to the text in a `TextField`:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Hint', 
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
  )
)
```